# Camera and Gallery not opening in Pixel 5 Devices only

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pixel

I'm trying to open gallery and camera to upload images into my app, the code is working on all other devices, but not working in Google Pixel 5. I tried with Pixel 4, and 4a everything works fine.

Can anyone suggest me as to why it is happening.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are facing a problem, consider sharing your code as it is the code that mostly contains the error.